# Does the Salesforce1 app work well with Bootstrap?

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform, bootstrap

I am developing a web app using bootstrap. To test on mobile, I installed Salesforce1 on my mobile. I ran the app in both mobile browser and the Salesforce1.

I noticed difference in the performance while running inside mobile browser and the Salesforce1 app. The Salesforce1 app is quite slow and hangs. Also potentially there could be bugs for different mobile OS versions, e.g Android 4.2 might not work as 4.3 or 4.4 or 5.0. Same thing goes for iOS. However, inside the mobile browser, it's quite smooth and less buggy (it's not perfect but it's better).

So this situation made me think that building web apps using bootstrap is best to view using a browser (mobile/desktop). But it might be not so good running in apps, because for apps developed using Lightning Components maybe the best. But is this proven? Or actually bootstrap will run well in both browser and apps?

If you know any resources that I can refer to, please provide a link.

> Note: I'm really not sure if this is an adequate question for this
>   forum.

Comment: Your ask is on topic, but the title could use some work. Something more like "Does the Salesforce1 app work well with Bootstrap?"

Comment: thanks for suggestion @sfdcfox, i changed the title.I am grateful because people took time to analyze and improve my language.indirectly I can improve my english .